# Strange missing value message from geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a really strange missing values message which is not reproducible and I also can't find the problem. Once I get the warning, once not, and by counting NAs, I don't find it.

```
> ggplot(jnk, aes(x=Experiment, y=Log2Intensity)) + 
+     geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
+     geom_point(aes(color=imputed), 
+                position=position_jitter(width=.4), 
+                alpha=.5) + #scatter dots, fill if imputed
+     scale_color_manual('Imputed', values = c(`TRUE`='blue', `FALSE`='orange')) +
+     scale_y_continuous(limits=range_intensities) +
+     facet_wrap(~ my_label, ncol = 10, nrow=5)
> ggplot(jnk, aes(x=Experiment, y=Log2Intensity)) + 
+     geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
+     geom_point(aes(color=imputed), 
+                position=position_jitter(width=.4), 
+                alpha=.5) + #scatter dots, fill if imputed
+     scale_color_manual('Imputed', values = c(`TRUE`='blue', `FALSE`='orange')) +
+     scale_y_continuous(limits=range_intensities) +
+     facet_wrap(~ my_label, ncol = 10, nrow=5)
Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
> apply(jnk, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
     my_label   Protein.IDs    Experiment     replicate       imputed Log2Intensity          page 
            0             0             0             0             0             0             0
```

### Edit

As I said, it isn't reproducible. Thanks to comments from markus I figured out, that my `range_intensities` hits exactly the maximum value of `jnk$Log2intensity` and this somehow produces this error, but not always. 
I have no idea what the problem with the arithmetic here is.

So just to demonstrate this was not a nonsense question:

```
> range_intensities[2] >= max(jnk$Log2Intensity)
[1] TRUE
> range_intensities[1] <= max(jnk$Log2Intensity)
[1] TRUE
> range_intensities[2] == max(jnk$Log2Intensity)
[1] TRUE
```

I wouldn't expect any warning.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data.

Comment: You might exclude one observation due to `scale_y_continuous(limits=range_intensities)`. See `ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2, 4))`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer The original data was is about 20000 lines, I didn't want to paste this. And since it is not reproducible, I couldn't narrow it down.

Comment: @markus it looks like this was the correct hint. I calculate the `range_intensities` on the complete data frame, `ink` is just a subset, but the highest value is in this subset... The calculated range was `c(22.9383871981762, 36.9822675137542)` by setting it to `c(22.93, 36.99)` it seems to solve the problem... Feel free to add this as an answer. Strange that it only sometimes warns.

Comment: I still wonder, since it is in the range, but it was the maximum value... Need to `floor` and `ceiling` my ranges in the future....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the combination of jitter and limits:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3)

library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)
ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width=.4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3))

set.seed(1)
ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width=.4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3))
#Warning message:
#Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Comment: Lesson: Always set a seed if you use random numbers in your analyses.

Comment: I do actually at the beginning of the script! But I got this error by executing the whole script and by digging into the problem, I am of course don't set it again :-) So yeah, this is the problem, I see...